# Android SharedPreferences Capacity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

just want to ask **Android how many data is SharedPreferences able to store?**

I'm asking because i'm developing an Alarm App using shared preferences.

**Is it ideal to use shared preferences in alarm application to save time and other settings?**

Or what's the best way to do it?

any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925194/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-android-shared-preference-value) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617825/shared-preferences-limit).

If you are not storing big amounts of data, the SharedPreferences are just fine, which I believe is your case.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how many Alarms do you want to store.

**10** Alarms? **SharedPreferences** are OK.
**100** Alarms? An **XML file** will do.
**1000** Alarms? Better use a **db**.