# Android sharedpreferences size limit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I just started developing an `android` application. My question is: what is the maximum size of `sharedpreferences` in `xml` format that can be retrieved at once?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

logically there is no limit for sharedpreferences because it saved inside your app look at this answer i think its perfectly right

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925194/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-android-shared-preference-value?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: I want to know how much data can I read from sharedprefernce at a time. My data size is greater than 1Mb will it make any performance issue with the app.