# Shared Preference size limit

Tags: android, gson

I am developing a simple android app in which I need to cache 4 ArrayLists and each has 50 objects. It may contain up to 1MB data. For this, I am using SharedPreference.

Is this fine to use SharedPreference for my use case or should I use Internal Storage(FileOutputStream)?

What is the size limit of SharedPreference?

I don't want to use SQLite for such small amount of data and it will complicate the code.

Comment: "Is this fine to use SharedPreference for my use case or should I use Internal Storage?" -- `SharedPreferences` and SQLite databases are both stored on internal storage by default. "Internal storage" is not a type of file.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my question.

Comment: [have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) i think this is what you beed

Comment: @nasser I have already gone through this. I want to know how much data I can store in SharedPreference, is there any limit?

Comment: If you feel that your arraylists deserve better structuring and may scale up in the future, use Sqlite (or better, use ORM). If you feel you need simple getter, setter functionality, use SharedPreferences. However, make sure size constraints exist for the app in the future, since SharedPreferences may throw error. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311359/android-sharedpreferences-size-limit)

Comment: Yes, My need is simple. My app is showing top 50 results for which I am using ArrayList. I am using APIs for fetching the data from the server. I just need to cache this data locally so a user can see it when the internet connection is not available.

Answer (score 0):

the lowest size limit that I am aware of will be your amount of free heap space, as SharedPreferences reads that entire XML file's contents into memory. Since SharedPreferences are stored in an XML file, and therefore lacks the strong transaction support of SQLite . if you are storing more than 100k go with sqlite

Answer (score -1):

[based on @CommonsWare answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617825/shared-preferences-limit)

> Since SharedPreferences are stored in an XML file, and therefore lacks
> the strong transaction support of SQLite, I would not recommend
> storing "100KBS" in SharedPreferences.
>
> That being said, the lowest size limit that I am aware of will be your
> amount of free heap space, as SharedPreferences reads that entire XML
> file's contents into memory.

i think its better if you use SQLite databases

Comment: What about writing the data to a text file? [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460508/2970035)

Comment: There is no limits on any resources now after Android2.3 release the new aapt

Comment: Do you mean that I can use SharedPreference now? Can you share from where did you get this information?

Comment: "7.6.2. Application Shared Storage
Device implementations MUST offer shared storage for applications. The shared storage provided MUST be at least 1GB in size." read it from https://source.android.com/compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf so based on this you dont have predefined limit just you use whats remain of storage after previous app used