# App Inventor: TinyDB Record Limit, Or Size Limit

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've searched all my books and all over the web, including the `TinyDB` [site](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#TinyDB) itself, and can't find an answer to this question: is there any upper limit for number of records or filesize in a `TinyDB` implementation?

I'm working on a new app that could allow the user to enter up to hundreds of records, each consisting of maybe 6 text fields, and can't figure out if `TinyDB` can handle that large a recordset.

Comment: is your question about **App Inventor and TinyDB** or are you talking about **TinyDB** which is *a query processing system for extracting information from a network of TinyOS sensors* ? What is the TinyDB site you are talking about, any link?

Comment: yes its about App Inventor and TinyDB

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

**What is the maximum number of tags `TinyDB` can store?**

Under the hood, `TinyDB` is implemented in terms of [android.content.SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). According to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4925194/1545993), share preferences are represented as an XML file stored in `/data/data/[package name]/shared_prefs/[app name].xml`. **So the only space limitations involved are whether the device can store this file**. There is no inherent limit on the number of tags.

**What is the maximum size (length, number of characters) of each tag's content?**

The content of each tag (which can be an arbitrary value) is converted to JSON and is stored as a string. As in the answer to question #1, there is no inherent limitation on the size of this string.

---

Answers taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/AX1gPrAcuvY/2PWHn_NxrrsJ). Thank you Lyn.