# Shared Preferences - max length of a single value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am storing String into shared preferences, but I wasn't able to find out maximal length of string I can store. Do you know this value?

Comment: If it is really huge, like over 10 kilobyte, you might want to save it some other way, maybe a file on disk.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

By **[Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)** From the Question [Asked Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4954f180d8b71f21),

> Whatever the maximum length of a Java string is. So something like 
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE chars.

I suppose while SharedPreference is an XML file stored with One Tag if you store only One Pair/Object.
So there is no limit to write String in that if you think like you are writing in a file..(Theoretically)

But *Actually* what happens is that, while you are assigning value **to SharedPreference** using `put/get` function at that time you **Reading/Writting value in String Object**..so the *limit becomes to store value at one time equal to Size limit of String Object of Java*.

So while writting the code: *Limit of SharedPreference String Size = Java String Object Size Limit*(Practically)

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2147483647.

Answer (score 26):

Shared preference is stored in `/data/data/[package_name]/shared_prefs/[app name].xml`, I think there's **no limit** as per android architecture.

Comment: Is shared preference safe place to keep api token in android mobile app? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Use EncryptedSharedPreferences

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/encrypted_shared_preferences

Answer (score 21):

When I trying to save the max length string into the SharedPreferences in my device, it throw a Memory Exception when SharedPreferences data exceed 1.42 MB.

So if you have more than 1.42 MB data size to save its better to save use SQLite database.

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences):

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd
>   like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.