# Make a app similar to quiz maker utilizing the local storage sample app

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I wanted to check with more experienced developers if this is a good approach. In simple terms I wish to make a cin for the question and a cin with a boolean for the answer. The user would be required to input both and then it would be saved elsewhere to be utilized in another page.

Comment: You could use [nativescript-localstorage](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage/), it stores data in a JSON file internally. Its easy to use when compared to [nativescript-sqlite](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/) or [nativescript-couchbase-plugin](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-couchbase-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Applications Settings":
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/application-settings

The storage of a JavaScript object can be done with JSON.stringify() and you can recover it with JSON.parse().

Max length of a single value:

- Android: [Shared Preferences - max length of a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516812/shared-preferences-max-length-of-a-single-value)
- iOS: [Is there any limit in storing values in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing well all this time. The only difference was the lack of displaying the variable in which the [text] HTML command did it  for me.