# Not able to retrieve proper value from stored shared preference in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have use shared preferences for store api token.but it not return full token. always missing some letters from end of token.

this is how a tried.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("bearer_token", response.data!.accessToken ?? "");


SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
token = prefs.get('bearer_token').toString();
```

Comment: do you get result from `esponse.data!.accessToken`

Comment: yes. issue is not store full length of string in preferences @YeasinSheikh

Comment: can share the length of the token. also I can find only [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setString.html) limitation. Also it will be `prefs.getString`

Comment: 1012 characters are there @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accept null value while receiveing you need to change

```dart
token = prefs.get('bearer_token').toString();
```

to

```dart
token = prefs.getString('bearer_token');// now it return nullable string
```

And it should define like `String? token;`.

Also you are saving empty string on null case.

You can do

```dart
prefs.setString("bearer_token", response.data?.accessToken ?? "");
```

Now check empty string like

```dart
final result = prefs.getString('bearer_token')??"";
if(result.isEmpty){
  ///....
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But token is store correctly,issue is stored tokens last letters are missing.is there any length limitations like thing @Yeasin

Comment: I've found [Shared Preferences - max length of a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517309/10157127)