# Load SharedPreference efficient

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, if-statement

In my app I get a bug that makes me unable to load the SharedPreferences. The reason this happens is that when the applications is killed for good(task killer or phone restart) the phone can not load everything again. For now I am using this technique:

```
if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")) == "Example1"){

//do something
 }
else if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")) == "Example2"){

 //do something
 }
 else if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")) == "Example3"){

 //do something
}
else{
//do nothing
}
```

Since I got around 75 else if statements my phone refuses to load them after the app is killed. Are there any more efficient way of loading and then do something?(Note: I got more then one single SharedPreference)

Comment: You say that you have more than one pref, but I would still read them into variables before doing youre else-ifs... In the sample you provided above, you load the same pref 3 times.

Comment: I got five different "EXA1" like "EXA2","EXA3" and so on. Can you show me an example of variables being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharedPreferences does not work if many is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544275/sharedpreferences-does-not-work-if-many-is-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **strObject.equals("MatchString")** method

See:

```
if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")).equals("Example1")){
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

//do something
 }
else if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")).equals("Example2")){

 //do something
 }
 else if ((sharedPreferences.getString("EXA1", "")).equals("Example3")){

 //do something
}
else{
//do nothing
}
```

You can not compare two String object using **==** operator, because it is NOT Primitive Data Type.

Comment: Will this remove my bug? It still seems to do exactly the same only that you have replaced == with equals.

Comment: Why are you asking me?!!!, I just gave you the way I know, now your work is to check it at your code side.

Comment: Sorry had to wait a few minutes befor accepting for some reason:)