# Save about 30 String Data in SharedPreferences and it Show java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-sharedpreferences

I want to save about 30 String data in my android app, but sometimes in android phone with almost full memory, this error appear:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>              at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.(FastXmlSerializer.java)
>              at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:177)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:596)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:511)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:532)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
>              at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:454)

Is this still good to save about 30 string in sharedpreference?

I have read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199961/3167956) to not create a new editor for each change, maybe I have to change for some String change that call new editor, is that have a big contribution to prevent java.lang.OutOfMemoryError or I must do other else?

Comment: how big are they? i mean Strings

Comment: Each String contain at least 10-20 character of alphabet and numeric @pskink

Comment: at least 10-20 and at most? 1M?

Comment: yeah, average about 10-20, is that a problem to use sharedpreferences (too big) ? @pskink

Comment: @Redturbo Have you fixed this OOME ? I am facing the same. Share the experience of fixing this Would be helpful to explore more about to get an idea to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not store large amount of data in SharedPrefrences. Depending upon your mobile device you can store 1~2MB or even less. If you need to store large amount of data, then it is safe to use sqlLite database. There are several simple sqlLite library like http://satyan.github.io/sugar/